# Timber Twig and ACF Get image from custom field on taxonomy page

Tags: timber

Just like the title, I'm trying to get an image from a custom field I attached to a taxonomy. I currently have a taxonomy called city and the term would be some like Albuquerque, NM. I have created an image custom field ('city_hero_image') with ACF's and selected the ID as the return value. Looking at the source, in the src tag it says 'unknown' and when doing a print_r it returns basically an empty object array.

My taxonomy-city.php is

```
$context['posts'] = Timber::get_posts();
$context['categories'] = Timber::get_terms('city');

$cover_image_id = get_field('city_hero_image');
$context['cover_image'] = new TimberImage($cover_image_id);
Timber::render( $templates, $context );
```

In my taxonomy-city.twig I have

```
<img src="{{cover_image.get_url}}" class="img-responsive" alt="">
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### get_field in default WordPress

When you run [`get_field`](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/), the function will try to guess the object where it should look for the custom field from the context. The context is normally The Loop.

So, if you run `$cover_image_id = get_field( 'city_hero_image' );`, ACF will try get the custom field `city_hero_image` from the current post’s ID, which it can’t find. There’s also no `city_hero_image` defined on a post, it’s defined on your term.

- If you run `get_field` inside the loop, it will take the current post’s ID to load a field. But, with Timber you’re never inside The Loop. Timber is in fact used to get rid of The Loop.
- If you want to load a field from a term object (in your case `city_hero_image`), you’d need to explicitly tell `get_field` to look in that taxonomy with `get_field( 'city_hero_image', 'city_termid' )`, while termid will be the id of the term you want the data for.

### get_field in Timber

In Timber, `get_field` works a little different. Timber will populate the post or term object with the custom fields as properties.

If you have a custom field `city_hero_image` in your taxonomy, you can access it in multiple ways:

**in PHP**

- Directly via its property: `$category->city_hero_image`
- Through the `get_field` method of a Timber\Term object:
  `$category->get_field('city_hero_image)`

**in Twig**

- Directly via its property: `{{ category.city_hero_image }}`
- Through the `gef_field` method:
  `{{ category.get_field('city_hero_image') }}`

The same works for ACF fields on Timber\Post objects. You only need to call `get_field` explicitly when you want to access data of field types Repeater or Flexible Content.

### Putting it together

Let’s look at this in your example. You first need to get the term that is displayed. For archive pages, you can use the function `get_queried_object()`, which will return an object depending on the archive that is accessed:

- For term archives, it will be a `WP_Term` object.
- For post type archives, it will be a `WP_Post_Type` object.
- For author archives, it will be a `WP_User` object.
- and so on...

You have a term archive (`taxonomy-city.php`), so it would be

```
$term = new \Timber\Term( get_queried_object() );
$cover_image = $term->city_hero_image;

$context['term'] = $term;
$context['cover_image'] = new \Timber\Image($cover_image);
```

Comment: Awesome! Wow! TY! for this write up of explanations and work. Though Im still a little hazy as to what city term id I should use.

I got it working with the code you shared using the latter foreach and for categories loop. One thing, I'm running into is that is when I'm on another city term page and add an image, the other image from the previous one shows as well. Basically I'm trying to add one hero image per city taxonomy term page while on the front end, the term page serves up the appropriate archive of posts and has a hero image of its city.

Comment: @lnickel Hey, in that case I messed up a little. Maybe I have confused you, because I misunderstood what you want to achieve. Of course you want to display all posts for that taxonomy, and not all taxonomies! What I first proposed didn’t make much sense when I looked at it again. I updated the section «Putting it together» to match what you probably want to achieve. Hope that works for you!

Comment: Totally cool! You are really good!!! Worked like a charm! I wish there were more documentation on how to work with taxs like this for noobs. :)